# Why am I getting this error when creating an SQL query in MATLAB?

Tags: postgresql, matlab, sql

I'm trying to export some data from MATLAB to a database. I use a PostgreSQL database via ODBC as follows. First, I create the connection:

```
dbConn = database('PostgreSQL30', username,password);
```

If I try to execute some test insertion manually, everything looks fine:

```
exec( dbConn, 'insert into test(std) values(2.2)')
```

When I try to generate some short query dynamically, everything still looks fine:

```
q = sprintf('insert into test(std) values(%2.2f)', 12.345);
res = exec(dbConn, q);
```

But when I try to generate some query containing strings, I get an error:

```
>> q = sprintf('insert into test(name) values("%s")', 'xxx')

q =

insert into test(name) values("xxx")

>> res = exec(dbConn, q);
>> res.Message
ans =

ERROR: column "xxx" does not exist;
Error while executing the query
```

There is no difference if I use `"%s"` format or plain `%s`. Where is the problem?

**EDIT**

OK, I used the wrong quotation marks. When I use:

```
q = sprintf('insert into test(name) values(''%s'')', 'xxx')
```

everything is OK. So the question can be closed/deleted. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be closed. It may help someone else who comes here with the same problem.

Comment: on an unrelated note, I once used **pgmex** library to interface with PostgreSQL from MATLAB (uses the libpq C library directly): http://www.dertech.com/pgmex/pgmex.html

Comment: but the built-in functions to communicate matlab with postgres are quite good, is there any significant difference in using pgmex?

Comment: the built-ins connect using ODBC, as opposed to using the native C API functions though mex. Therefore its a performance issue since you can think of ODBC as a middleware layer...

Comment: I see, but for such simple usings as mine, ODBC is fine. BTW, there is some kind of built-in postgre driver in Matlab, but I didn't succeed in running it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: did you add the corresponding JDBC jar file to the javaclasspath? you can get the latest PostgreSQL JDBC driver at http://jdbc.postgresql.org

Comment: YUp, that was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using single quotes?

```
>> q = sprintf('insert into test(name) values(''%s'')', 'xxx')

q =

insert into test(name) values('xxx')
```

Comment: Yup, I came up with the same thing. Thanks for the answer.