# error Unknown column in 'where clause' matlab using an array of strings

Tags: sql, matlab

I want to read a column from a table of data base and for every row that I have read, read some rows from another table. the elements that I read from both tables are Strings, my code is:

```
query1 = 'select col1 from MyDb.table1 order by col1'; 
[x1]= mysql(query1);
     for i=1:size(x1)
         my=char(x1(i,1));    
         query2=sprintf('%s%s%s%s',['select col1 from MyDb.table2 where col1=', my, ' or col2=', my]);
         [x2]=mysql(query2); 
     end
```

when I run the code I get this error:Unknown column 'khlkuu'
in 'where clause', khlkuu is a row in first table. I know that this error is because of not surrounding khlkuu with quotation , but I do not know how to do so. any Ideas?

Comment: Related question: [Why am I getting this error when creating an SQL query in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941439/why-am-i-getting-this-error-when-creating-an-sql-query-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4):

To get quotes in a string, you need to use double-quotes. Also, the call to `sprintf` seems unnecessary.

```
my = 'something';
query2= ['select col1 from MyDb.table2 where col1=''', my, ''' or col2=''', my,'''']

query2 =
select col1 from MyDb.table2 where col1='something' or col2='something'
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer Jonas, you made it so easier :)