# passing string in a query to MySQL database in MATLAB

Tags: mysql, database, string, matlab

I am using MySQL with MATLAB, and I want to get a name from user, and pass it to the table in mySQL, but it is rejecting a variable name in place of string

```
var_name=input('enter the name:');

mysql('insert into table (name) values (var_name)');
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have mysql but i think this would works for you:    `mysql( horzcat('insert into table ', name, ' values ', var_name));`

Comment: Hi Ibtesam, Welcome to StackOverflow! Both @Isaac and Amro have posted correct answers, so you have three to choose from now ;-). The reasoning behind all this is that MATLAB has no way of telling that you meant var_name to be a variable and not just some characters you wanted to pass to the mysql function...

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks for telling the behind story. I was too lazy to explain that. =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you are having is the same as the one in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1941439/52738). It sounds like you want to create a command string that itself contains a `'` delimited string, which would require you to escape each `'` with another `'` when you create your command string (note the first example in [this string handling documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strings.html)). Note also you may want to use the `'s'` option for the [INPUT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/input.html) function:

```
var_name = input('Enter the name: ','s');  %# Treats input like a string
commandString = sprintf('insert into table (name) values (''%s'')', var_name);
                            %# Note the two apostrophes --^
mysql(commandString);
```

If I were to enter `Ken` for the input, the string `commandString` would contain the following:

```
insert into table (name) values ('Ken')
```

And of course, as others have already mentioned, beware [injection vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 3):

**FIRST** read the comments to this question - you don't want to shoot yourself in the foot with a mysql injection security problem. You have been warned. Now, to solve your current problem, without addressing the security risk of the whole approach when it comes to building SQL queries, read on...

In principle Amro has already posted two solutions for you which work, but since you have not accepted it I'll explain further.

Your problem is that you are not telling MATLAB which parts of your query it should interpret as a literal string, and which parts it should interpret as a variable name. To solve this, you can just *end* the literal string where appropriate, i.e. after the opening brackets, and then start them again before the closing brackets.

In between those literal strings you want to add the *contents* of your variables, so you need to tell MATLAB to concat your literal strings with your variables, since the mysql command probably expects the whole query as a single string. So in essence you want to take the string 'insert into table(' and the string saved in the variable `name` and the string ') values (' and so on and glue them into one big string. Amro and Isaac have shown you two solutions of how to do this without much explanation:

```
horzcat('insert into table (', name, ') values (', var_name, ')')
```

uses the function [horzcat](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/horzcat.html), while

```
['insert into table (' name ') values (' var_name ')']
```

uses the fact that MATLAB treats strings as arrays of characters so that you can just use square brackets to form a large array containing the strings one after the other.

The third solution, offered by Amro, is a bit more sublte:

```
sprintf('insert into table (%s) values (%s)',name,var_name)
```

It tells the function [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) (which is made for that purpose) "take the string which I supply as first parameter and replace occurences of `%s` with the strings I supply as the following parameters. This last technique is in particular useful if you also need to insert numbers into your string, because `sprintf` can also convert numbers to string and allows fine control over how they are formatted. You should have a close look at the [help page for sprintf](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) to know more :-).

Comment: One more step - you probably need to convert the string in `var_name` to an SQL string literal, and sanitize the input to avoid Bobby Tables issues.

Comment: @Ibtesam: Andrew is right: have a look at http://bobby-tables.com/ or other sources about SQL injection attacks and make sure the `mysql()` function that you plan to use is not a security risk! It is okay if you yourself will be the only one typing in the `var_name` and `name` values, but if anyone else will be using this, be very carful!

Comment: @Ibtesam: one more to convince you: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
mysql(['insert into table (' name ') values (' var_name ')']);
```

or even:

```
mysql(sprintf('insert into table (%s) values (%s)',name,var_name));
```

Comment: thanks @Amro for a prompt reply, but the thing is that anything written withing '' is treated as a string and not as a variable. I want to pass it a variable that contains the string.

Comment: @Ibtesam: this is string concatenation. Ex: `str = 'hello '; disp([str 'world'])`